# Delete item from database after X days

Tags: java, mysql, sql, datetime, jdbi

I am trying to make a Java Thread, this thread have to delete from an MySQL database all the records, older than 7 days.

In my table i have a column that contain the date like this: `2013-10-28 17:00:00` .

And to do this i want to use JDBI library. and my question here if any one could give me and example of the query that i have to write.

I think it should look like this:

```
h.execute("Delete from  MyTable where date >= (dt.now.dayofmonth() -7)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`h.execute("DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE NOW() >= ADDDATE(date, INTERVAL 7 DAY);");`

Answer (score 1):

Try this::

```
h.execute("Delete from  MyTable where DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), dateCOLUMN)>7");
```

Answer (score 0):

"`delete from MyTable where date >= date_sub(now(), interval 7 day)`"